# Getting to virtual terminal with Keytouch overriding Fn keys

Tags: 11.10, command-line, shortcut-keys, login-screen, fstab

I have a Chromebook running Ubuntu that I just broke.  I had everything on the internal harddrive for the computer, but ran out of space, so I decided to move my home partition onto a memory card that would stay in it's slot.

I setup my home partition on the memory card and changed the fstab file to point to it as the home partition.  When I rebooted my system I couldn't login to my user (kept refreshing the login screen when I enter username and password).

After figuring out that the problem was with my new home partition I figured I'd just boot to a virtual terminal and change everything back since I should've been able to login there from what I've read on other forums.  The problem is that I have keytouch running which overrides all of my Fn keys so I can't get to a virtual terminal.  Is there another way, from the login screen, to get to some form of a terminal that can edit the fstab file and move directories around?

I am running Ubuntu Desktop 11.10

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned. Unaccepted answer or unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Flagged for deletion. Thanks!